# Get first character of each element of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df. It has a column called 'Spec Type'. Using pandas,

```
df['Spec Type']

0         NaN
1          A1
2         G7V
3       F7+K4
.         .
.         .
169       A0e
```

I want to get only the first character for each entry and make it as a new column of df called 'Spec Type Index'. However, the following code gives me an error:

```
df['Spec Type Index'] = [i[0] for i in df['Spec Type']]
```

> 'float' object is not subscriptable

The error is in the i[0] part. I use it to get the first character of the indexed element. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Spec Type'].notnull(), 'Spec Type Index'] = df['Spec Type'].str[0]
```

should work, the problem is the `NaN` is a float dtype so you can't use str methods, masking like the above avoids that

```
In [48]:
df.loc[df['Spec Type'].notnull(), 'Spec Type Index'] = df['Spec Type'].str[0]
df

Out[48]:
      Spec Type Spec Type Index
index                          
0           NaN             NaN
1            A1               A
2           G7V               G
3         F7+K4               F
```

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me an exact copy of Spec Type, not first character only of each element, say 'A' of 'A1' element.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer, also is my output matching yours?